# How to set Proxy setting for vaadin TestBench in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, vaadin, http-proxy, test-bench

i need to connect to vaadin server for validating the vaadin Testbench license.i wrote code in java programme as

```
     System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "www-proxy.cccc.cccccccc.de");
     System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1234");
     System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
     System.out.println("in IE");
     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                    "C:\\Users\\ProjectJars\\Selenium\\IEDriiver\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.9.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
setDriver(new InternetExplorerDriver());
```

i am getting the following error ;
**Your license for TestBench 4 has not been validated. Check your network connection.**
i am behind the proxy , here i need to set the proxy settings to connect to server for validation . i am trying with IE driver. I am not using maven.
i also set Proxy settings in seetings.xml of maven

```
-<proxy>

<id>optional1</id>

<active>true</active>

<protocol>http</protocol>

<username/>

<password/>

<host>www-ccccc.ccccc.cccccccccc.com</host>

<port>1234</port>

<nonProxyHosts> 111.111.11.1|localhost|111.1.1.1 </nonProxyHosts>

</proxy>
```

i changed the values and proxy name here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is somewhat old, but still relevant discussion about this in Vaadin Forum. Namely you need to configure jvm parameters, so that Java can access internet via proxy

https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/13408660/13871749

More generic document is here

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html